# Creating INSERT-Statements to export the data from every exisiting table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, export, sql-insert

I am currently not able to get a proper database dump, because the DB runs on a remote server inside a closed system --> no remote copying possible, only way to get files in/out is by being physically present at the servers location or via e-Mail (but I can't send a several GB big dump via mail...).

However, I still need the data in order to import it into my dev system.

I figure the best way of doing this is by creating INSERT statements that contain the needed information.

The SQL-Developer software can actually do this, but apparently it only works for one table at a time. As soon as one selects multiple tables the respective option disappears from the right-click-menu and one can only export the DDL statements :-/

So this approach is not really viable for me, as there are hundreds of tables...

Does anyone know of a standardized way to create INSERT statements via the querying of metadata tables (user_tables, user_columns, ...)? I could imagine that it might be possible to create all the statements by cleverly joining those meta tables. However, before dumping several hours into this approach, I'd appreciate if someone can confirm this suspicion first.

Also someone else must have had this problem before, so I hope that some of you may be able to give me a hint on other approaches. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i know you can do this in the purchased version of TOAD, there is also a free version which may be worth a look at to see if it allows this kind of thing

Comment: you should be able to define a database link. Than you could run a script of CTAS for each table (create as select from the source via [db link](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5006.htm#SQLRF01205)).

Answer (score 0):

My answer isn't full solution. 
1) To extract DDL use.

```
select table_name,dbms_metadata.get_ddl(OBJECT_TYPE=>'TABLE', NAME=>table_name) from user_tables;
```

2) To extract record from table use xmltype (refucursor) and dbms_xmlstore to insert them. 
Below only suggestion how to do this.

```
create table test as select level as "LP" from dual connect by level < 100;

declare 
 v_cursor sys_refcursor;
 xmlDoc xmltype; 
 curid    NUMBER;
 insCtx DBMS_XMLSTORE.ctxType;
 rows NUMBER;
begin
  open v_cursor for 'select * from test';
    xmlDoc  := xmltype(v_cursor); 
  close v_cursor;
  dbms_output.put_line(xmlDoc.getClobVal()); -- extracted row into xml. 

  insCtx := DBMS_XMLSTORE.newContext('test'); 
  DBMS_XMLSTORE.clearUpdateColumnList(insCtx); 
  rows := DBMS_XMLSTORE.insertXML(insCtx, xmlDoc); 
  dbms_output.put_line('ROWS inserted' || rows);
   DBMS_XMLSTORE.closeContext(insCtx); 
   commit;
end;
```